# Using the diameter of a set in the proof that a bounded and closed set is compact (Heine-Borel in Rn)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

My goal is to prove that a closed and bounded set is compact. I have constructed a topological argument using the notion of diameter. My question is whether or not my proof is logically sound. Thank you.

*Proof:*
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual metric be a closed and bounded set. I will connect the ideas of closed and boundedness using the diameter. Let $D$ be the diameter of $A$, defined as $ D = \max\{d(x,y) : x,y \in A\}$. Since $D$ is bounded, we know that the diameter of $A$ exists as a finite number, (otherwise there would not exist an open ball of radius $r$ that contains $A$, per the def of bounded) Since $D$ is closed, we know that $A$ contains the arguments of the maximum, $x^\star, y^\star$ (the elements that connect the diameter).

Suppose that $A$ is not compact. Then there exists an open cover $C$, such that any subcover does not cover $A$. Suppose that this open cover is defined as $C = \{B_r^n (x^\star)\}_{r \in \mathbb{R}}$, the collection of open balls of radius $r$, centered at $x^\star$. Clearly, as $C$ covers $\mathbb{R}^n$, it must cover $A$. However, any sub cover $C^\prime = \{B_{r_1}, B_{r_2}, \dotsc, B_{r_k}\}$ does not cover $A$ by assumption. Hence, for any $C^\prime$, there exists an $y \in A$, such that $y \notin \cup_{i = 1}^k B_{r_i}$. Suppose that $r^\star = \max \{r_1, r_2, \dotsc, r_k\}$. This implies that the element $y \in A$  is *further* away from $x^\star$ than the largest radius $r^\star$ is long (suppose $y$ is the furthest element), hence $y = y^\star$. We clearly see that $r^\star \leq D$. Since $r^\star$ can becomes arbitrarily large, this means that $D$ becomes arbitrarily large, which produces a contradiction, namely that $D$ is not a finite number. Therefore, $A$ must be compact.

**QED**

Comment: Usually the diameter of A is defined as $\sup \{d(x,y) : x,y \in A\}$. How  do you get the existence of $x^\star, y^\star$ without using the (a posteriori) compactness of $A$?

Comment: +1 for comment of @FormulaWriter. This is a genuine concern which needs to be addressed in your proof. Essentially it means showing $d(x, y) $ to be continuous and hence attaining max somewhere because its domain is closed and bounded.

Comment: A typical proof of Heine Borel starts by first reducing an open cover to a countable subcover (Lindelof covering theorem which works for any set) and then reduce it to a finite subcover (which works only when set is closed and bounded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this proof checks out. You're first assuming that there is an open cover $C$ that has no (finite) subcover. Then, in the next step, you are assuming a very particular form for the cover $C$. Do you see why that is logically not allowed? There is no reason for the cover $C$ to consist of balls with the same center.

You might be able to remedy your proof by choosing $C$ in this way, but then you have to prove explicitly that it doesn't admit a finite subcover, something which I don't think is true.

I think you are better off by trying to reduce it to Heine-Borel in $\mathbb{R}$ by using the projection onto each of the components. Since $A$ is bounded, it fits inside of a closed rectangle $R$. Then, $R = [a_1, b_1] \times .... \times [a_n,b_n]$ is compact as the product of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Finally, $C$ is a closed subset of a compact, hence, it is compact itself.

Answer (score 1):

"Suppose that this open cover is defined as $C = \{B_r^n (x^\star)\}_{r \in \mathbb{R}}$"

There's your problem.  You can't "suppose" that, because an open cover could be uncountable.  A better approach is by induction - we'll assume that any closed bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is compact.  (I'll omit the base case, $\mathbb{R}$, since I assume you already know it.)  Then for $\mathbb{R}^n$, you consider an open cover.  Since it's a cover, for every line corresponding to a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, it must be a cover of that line, and since the Heine-Borel theorem holds for $\mathbb{R}$, every such point must be associated with a finite subcover.  The unions of these subcovers themselves are a cover of the cross-section, so they also must have a finite subcover by the inductive hypothesis, so you just have to take that finite subcover and break each element back down into the finite subset of the original cover that created it to get a finite subcover of the original set.